# document.execCommand ('copy') don't work in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, execcommand

I have the function below that is called on click of a button . Everything works well, but the `document.execCommand ('copy')` simply does not work.

If I create another button and call only the contents of `if` in a separate function, it works well.

I have already tried calling a second function inside the first one, but it also does not work. the copy is only working if it is alone in the function.

Does anyone know what's going on?

```
copyNshort = () => {
    const bitly = new BitlyClient('...') // Generic Access Token bit.ly
    let txt = document.getElementById('link-result')

    bitly.shorten(txt.value)
        .then((res) => {
            this.setState({ shortedLink: res.url })

            if (this.state.shortedLink !== undefined) {
                document.getElementById('link-result-shorted').select() // get textarea value and select
                document.execCommand('copy') // copy selected
                console.log('The link has been shortened and copied to clipboard!')
                ReactDOM.render(<i className="fas fa-clipboard-check"></i>, document.getElementById('copied'))
            }
            console.log('Shortened link ', res.url) // Shorted url
        })
}
```

Comment: `execCommand('copy')` works only via a direct user interaction, i.e. in an onclick or another event handler, I'm not sure, but fullfilling a promise might not considered as a user action ..? And the element from which to copy the content, must be visible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the `copy-to-clipboard` functionality will only work as a direct result of a user's `click` event listener... This event cannot be virtualised and the execCommand will not work anywhere else than the immediate callback assigned to the event listener...
Because react virtualises and abstracts 'events' then that's very possibly where the problem lies and as suggested you should be using React's `react-copy-to-clipboard`.

Comment: I had package importing issues with `react-copy-to-clipboard`. [react-clipboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-clipboard.js) is just working fine for me...

Answer (score 3):

You can use lib [react-copy-to-clipboard](https://github.com/nkbt/react-copy-to-clipboard) to copy text.

```
import {CopyToClipboard} from 'react-copy-to-clipboard';`

function(props) {
    return (
       <CopyToClipboard text={'Text will be copied'}>
           <button>Copy button</button>
       </CopyToClipboard>
    );
}
```

if you click button `Copy button`, it will copy the text `Text will be copied`

Comment: Thanks, but lib does the same thing I'm doing, and the problem will be exactly the same! xD

Answer (score -2):

The lib [react-copy-to-clipboard](https://github.com/nkbt/react-copy-to-clipboard) based on [copy-to-clipboard](https://github.com/sudodoki/copy-to-clipboard) does work for me, but if you want to copy the source into your own file, Some places need attention.
The code below works fine.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1
          onClick={e => {
            const range = document.createRange()
            const selection = document.getSelection()
            const mark = document.createElement('span')
            mark.textContent = 'text to copy'
            // reset user styles for span element
            mark.style.all = 'unset'
            // prevents scrolling to the end of the page
            mark.style.position = 'fixed'
            mark.style.top = 0
            mark.style.clip = 'rect(0, 0, 0, 0)'
            // used to preserve spaces and line breaks
            mark.style.whiteSpace = 'pre'
            // do not inherit user-select (it may be `none`)
            mark.style.webkitUserSelect = 'text'
            mark.style.MozUserSelect = 'text'
            mark.style.msUserSelect = 'text'
            mark.style.userSelect = 'text'
            mark.addEventListener('copy', function(e) {
              e.stopPropagation()
            })

            document.body.appendChild(mark)

            // The following line is very important
            if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
              selection.removeAllRanges()
            }

            range.selectNodeContents(mark)
            selection.addRange(range)
            document.execCommand('copy')
            document.body.removeChild(mark)
          }}
        >
          Click to Copy Text
        </h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1
          onClick={e => {
            const mark = document.createElement('textarea')
            mark.setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly')
            mark.value = 'copy me'
            mark.style.position = 'fixed'
            mark.style.top = 0
            mark.style.clip = 'rect(0, 0, 0, 0)'
            document.body.appendChild(mark)
            mark.select()
            document.execCommand('copy')
            document.body.removeChild(mark)

          }}
        >
          Click to Copy Text
        </h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```